# Substract 10 years from yesterdays date using Date.parse() method of date.js

Tags: javascript

am using the below code to substract 8 years from yesterday date. It is working fine.

```
var today = Date.parse("yesterday -96 months");
```

But when i give the below code to substract 10 years from yesterday date. It is not working

```
var today = Date.parse("yesterday -120 months");
```

Can any one suggest how to resolve this

Thanks.

Comment: by not working do you mean the date is wrong or the date is not calculated at all?

Comment: today = new Date(); today.setFullYear( today.getFullYear() - 1); is the usual way.

Comment: Try `Date.parse("yesterday -10 years")`

Comment: @artm - Yes, but that's for Gregorian calendar only.  For Chinese calendar you must use Date.parse("Year of the Sheep - 10 years); See [MDN Data.parse for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: I would recommend you use moment.js